# Get Financial Option Data with YQL

Tags: finance, yql

I am using YQL to retrieve Financial Option data. Something like:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.options where symbol="AAPL" and expiration="2011-07"
```

However, the above query returns an `optionsChain` of data.

Is there a way to retrieve just the record for a specific option symbol, e.g. `symbol=AAPL110716C00155000`?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can apply a "local filter", for your desired symbol, on the result set brought back from `yahoo.finance.options` in addition to the "remote filters" (`symbol` and `expiration`).

```
select option
from yahoo.finance.options
where symbol = "AAPL" 
  and expiration = "2011-07" 
  and option.symbol = "AAPL110716C00155000"
```

For more info on filtering query results see the [**Filtering Query Results (WHERE)**](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/select.html#filtering-query-results) page in the YQL documentation.

Comment: The YQL one seems to be having issues. Another one to try is Google has an Option API as well. I have a tutorial on it if anyone is looking for an alternative: http://www.jarloo.com/google-stock-options-api/

Comment: @sala the link is broken

Answer (score 0):

I just got all the optionsChain of data by :

```
select * from yahoo.finance.options where symbol="A" and expiration="2012-10"
```

And, then just used a JSON Parser to parse the optionsChain's data and got my desired data.